# Build Failing when using Github Action CI/CD

Tags: spring-boot, github, npm, cicd

I was using the CI CD Github Action for my build  and my build is failing for a branch on github. This is the error  i was having:

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.2:npm (npm run build) on project demo: Failed to run task: 'npm run build' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
Error:  
Error:  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/.../MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I try to run npm run build on my local and it work completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to in your pom.xml file, and if your code is like this

```
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                        ...

                        <execution>
                            <id>npm audit fix</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>

                            <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                       ...
             </plugin>
```

remove `<configuration>...</configuration>` part, and chnage to like this

```
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                        ...

                        <execution>
                            <id>npm audit fix</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>

                       ...
             </plugin>
```

in All of your `<execution>...</execution>`.
I hope your code will work finely.